# c# xml serialization with special characters like unicodes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, unicode

The object serialization in C# automatically serializes html tags and & signs.
But I have a string with values like below which is not getting converted to xml/html safe.

• TEST1 • TEST2 • TEST3
15 °C
36 °F

Please note that there are two special characters in my example string. One is a bullet and another is temperature symbol.

The code to serialize the object into xml is as bleow. What could be wrong here?

```
    public static String ToXmlString(this Object obj)
    {
        var objectType = obj.GetType();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(objectType);
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
        using (Utf8StringWriter writer = new Utf8StringWriter(xml))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        }
        return xml.ToString();
    }

    public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
    {
        public Utf8StringWriter(StringBuilder xml) : base(xml){}
        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are those characters not "xml/html safe"? There are only [five problematic characters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/596219) described in the specification (`"'<>&`), everything else can be encoded safely as-is.

Comment: Now I realized that its not xml unsafe but there is a problem with the encoding. Our downstream system is rejecting such xmls which has those characters. Even if I have that xml opened in internet explorer, its not showing correctly in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I have used XmlDocument instead of XmlSerialzier

```
public static String ToXmlString(this Object xmlObj)
        {
            var objectType = xmlObj.GetType();
            var document = new XmlDocument();
            document.LoadXml(xml: xmlObj.ToString());
            StringBuilder xmldata = new StringBuilder();
            var ele = (XmlElement)document.FirstChild;
            foreach(var item in document)
            {
                xmldata.Append(item);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(ele.InnerXml); 
            return xmldata.ToString();
        }
```